# App Store Review Guidelines - Do they agree with a completely password-protected application?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I have an app for iOS available only for the customers. On the main page, there is a login/password form. And there is no form to Sign Up because the registration is possible offline only.
In the review, I will provide the credentials (they are the same for all users, like user/qwerty), so Apple can check the functionality.
Will they approve that the app will not be public by default?
I'm reading their rules, and do not see any problems:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#legal

> (v) Account Sign-In: If your app doesn’t include significant
> account-based features, let people use it without a login. If your app
> supports account creation, you must also offer account deletion within
> the app. Apps may not require users to enter personal information to
> function, except when directly relevant to the core functionality of
> the app or required by law. If your core app functionality is not
> related to a specific social network (e.g. Facebook, WeChat, Weibo,
> Twitter, etc.), you must provide access without a login or via another
> mechanism. Pulling basic profile information, sharing to the social
> network, or inviting friends to use the app are not considered core
> app functionality. The app must also include a mechanism to revoke
> social network credentials and disable data access between the app and
> social network from within the app. An app may not store credentials
> or tokens to social networks off of the device and may only use such
> credentials or tokens to directly connect to the social network from
> the app itself while the app is in use.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide apple fully functional credentials as if they were a customer for them to properly review your app.

I would focus more on section 2.1 from what I’m seeing you ask for:

> ### 2.1 App Completeness
>
> Submissions to App Review, including apps you make available for pre-order, should be final versions with all necessary metadata and fully functional URLs included; placeholder text, empty websites, and other temporary content should be scrubbed before submission. Make sure your app has been tested on-device for bugs and stability before you submit it, and **include demo account info (and turn on your back-end service!) if your app includes a login**

You might slide by one or two reviews, but generally you should expect to not get on the App Store these days until you let them test the app as it will run.

Apple clearly reserves the right to flatly reject your app, so consider if you could pre-load sample customer data so that anyone that downloads the app can see it work. Also, consider if your app is really just a web app and should even be on the store at all if it’s just a portal for existing clients to log in.

Best of luck with your development efforts.

Comment: I provided them with test credentials. My question - will it be a problem, if these credentials could only be acquired offline?

Comment: Anything could be a problem - just wait, listen and react is my advice with App Review. Also - always wait 48 hours MINIMUM if you get a rejection before doing anything but make a small bug fix. Really think through - work on your next pitch if you run into resistance. you’re in the big leagues so giving their feedback real time to digest is never the wrong move.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there's absolutely no problems in having such an app, where account creation only happens offline.

As you mention, you will have to supply Apple with a test account. In my experience, it is not the case that they "forget" to ask for that a few times - that's always the first thing they ask for. They might also ask you to do a video recording of the app working as intended.